# Search of sentences ending with specific marks and frequency histogram

Tags: python, file, dictionary, count, histogram

I tried to make a frequency histogram of sentences which end with exclamation marks, question marks, as well as sentences ending with a dot in the text (I just counted the number of these characters in the text). The text is read from the file. The code I've done looks like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 
text_file = 'text.txt'
 
marks = '?!.'
lcount = dict([(l, 0) for l in marks])
 
 
for l in open(text_file, encoding='utf8').read():
    try:
        lcount[l.upper()] += 1
    except KeyError:
        pass
norm = sum(lcount.values())
 
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
x = range(3)
ax.bar(x, [lcount[l]/norm * 100 for l in marks], width=0.8,
       color='g', alpha=0.5, align='center')
ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_xticklabels(marks)
ax.tick_params(axis='x', direction='out')
ax.set_xlim(-0.5, 2.5)
ax.yaxis.grid(True)
ax.set_ylabel('Sentences with different ending frequency, %')
plt.show()
```

But I can’t count others sentence that end with an ellipsis(it means ...), my code counts as three characters, so three sentences. Moreover, this is count of symbols, not actually sentences. How can I improve with counting of sentences, not marks and counting of sentences ending with ellipsis? **Example of file:** *Wanna play? Let's go! It will be definitely good! My friend also think so. However, I don't know... I don't like this.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try splitting the sentences using a `regex`. The `re.split()` function works fine here:
Sample code:

```
import re
string = "Wanna play? Let's go! It will be definitely good! My friend also think so. However, I don't know... I don't like this."
print(re.split('\.+\s*|!+\s*|\?+\s*', string))
```

Output:

```
['Wanna play', "Let's go", 'It will be definitely good', 'My friend also think so', "However, I don't know", "I don't like this", '']
```

Edited answer: `re.findall('([^.?!]+\.+|[^.?!]+!+|[^.?!]+\?+)\s*', string)`

#### Explainantion:

1. `()` are used to capture and group the results of the sequence inside those. Eg.:

```
import re

a = 'Hello World'
print(re.findall('l+o', a))   # Match = llo, Output = llo
print(re.findall('(l+)o', a)) # Match = llo, output = ll
```

Output:

```
['llo']
['ll']  # With parenthesis, only the part inside them is returned
```

2. `[^.?!]+` Refers to a set of 1 or more characters except `.`, `?`, and `!`. This matches all the words and as soon as it encounters a punctuation out of the three, the criteria fails and the sraerch breaks.Eg.

```
import re

a = 'Hello World! My name is Anshumaan. What is Your name?'
print(re.findall('[^.?!]+', a))
print(re.findall('([^.?!]+)\!+\s*', a))
print(re.findall('([^.?!]+\!+)\s*', a))
```

Output:

```
['Hello World', ' My name is Anshumaan', ' What is Your name']
['Hello World']
['Hello World!']
```

It starts from the left, all characters until `!` match it and hence it returns them. Then it starts from the space since it also matches the criteria and goes until the `.`.
In the next case, `!` is also matched, but since only the word matching part is in the parentheses, `!` is not returned(\s* matches 0 or more whitespace).
In the 3rd case, since `\!` is also in the parentheses, `!` is also returned.

3. Finally, It is the `or` block. Since we have 3 punctuations there are 3 criteria, a word/phrase with`.`, a word/phrase with `!` and a word/phrase with `?`. They are all joined using an `or` character(`|`) and then in order to filter out whitespaces, the `\s` character is placed out of the parentheses.

So,

```
re.findall('([^.?!]+\.+|[^.?!]+!+|[^.?!]+\?+)\s*', string)
```

Can be interpreted as:

```
find: ('(<character except [.!?] once or more>and<! once or more>)' or '(<character except [.!?] once or more>and<. once or more>)' or '(<character except [.!?] once or more>and<? once or more>)')<also look for whitespace but don't return them since they are not in the parentheses>
```

Comment: Thanks! But how can I split sentences with keeping marks at the end?

Comment: In that case you can try: `re.findall('([^.?!]+\.+|[^.?!]+!+|[^.?!]+\?+)\s*', string)`

Answer (score 1):

By the look of you example, and a common way to handle words in NLP (with regards to lemmatization etc.) you can first split the sentences on spaces:

```
marks = ['?', '!', '...', '.'] # Ordering of ellipsis first gives prio of checking that condition 
mark_count = {}
sentences = 0

for example in file:
    words = example.split(" ") # This gives an array of all words togheter with your symbols
    
    # Finds markings in word
    for word in words:
        for mark in marks:
            if mark in word:
                # Here you will find and count end of sentence and break if found, as a 
                # word can be "know..." the first dot will be found and then we break as we know 
                # thats the end of the sentence.
                sentences += 1
                
                if mark_count.get(mark, False):
                    mark_count[mark] += 1
                else:
                    mark_count[mark] = 1

                break
```

---

Edit:

To guarantee correct pairing

```
columns = []
values = []
for key in mark_count.keys():
    columns.append(key)
    values.append(mark_count[key])

plt.bar(columns, values, color='green')
```

Comment: Thanks for good example, but I need to count separately sentences that end with dot and ellipsis.

Comment: Updated for handling off ellipsis, good luck! If you find a good solution, please do accept the solution you agree with for clarity for future persons who may visit the topic.

Comment: One more question: can i use mark_count{} for histogram in such way: plt.bar(list(mark_count.keys()), mark_count.values(), color='green')?

Comment: Updated my previous response, please take a look! I do not know if your solution guarantees the same orderings of keys togheter with values and would therefore do the manual way to ensure correct pairing.

Comment: The histogram should have 4 keys: dot, ellipsis, question and exclamation mark. It has only three and counting of them is wrong, cause the count of dots = 12, but i don't have there 12 sentences with dots, only 6